# SQLite calculations

Tags: sqlite

I'm running into a rather simple problem and I can't determine whether the problem is my SQLite gui (tried 2 btw with same results) or SQLite itself. When I run the following

`SELECT (30/24)-1 as 'calc'`

I get 0 instead of the expected .25

Now obviously this is not my actual query but when it started getting the same result with actual numbers I got worried

Please let me know whether this is an SQLite issue or an issue with my SQLite Manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your query is rounding down to zero, as it's being cast implicitly to an Integer.

Have you tried **explicitly** casting your numbers/result to a decimal?

Comment: for practical purposes this is a better solution

Answer (score 2):

You need to move from integer to floating arithmetic.  E.g. change the 30 to 30.0 and you'll get your required result:

```
SELECT (30.0/24)-1 as 'calc'
```